# gatsby build fails when adding mapbox-gl-geocoder to gatsby.js

Tags: mapbox, gatsby, netlify, mapbox-gl

I have a gatsby.js application with **mapbox-gl** and it all worked successfully until I tried to include the **mapbox-gl-geocoder** package to add search functionality.

I have installed it using npm as the following:

`npm install mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder --save`

then, added it to the React component:

```
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css';
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
```

and inside a useEffect hook:

```
  map.addControl(
      new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        zoom: 20,
        placeholder: 'Enter City',
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl
      }), 'top-left'
    );
```

locally, when I run `gatsby develop` it works as it should, but when I deploy it with Netlify, I get the following error:

```
:24:21 PM: error Generating SSR bundle failed
1:24:21 PM: Can't resolve 'electron' in '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/node_modules/got'
1:24:21 PM: If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'electron' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
```

it seems that mapbox-gl-geocoder has a dependency to @mapbox/mapbox-sdk and the mapbox-sdk has a dependency to got that somehow needs electron ?

The only thing i can read about electron in the got npm page is the following:

```
Electron support has been removed
The Electron net module is not consistent with the Node.js http module. See #899 for more info.
```

In any way, I tried to install electron with npm to see if the errors are gone, and the build started to fail with new error indicating that the window object is not available.

```
10:35:45 AM: error "window" is not available during server side rendering.
```

Googling that error led me to some answers about not loading the packages in `gatsby-node.js` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with third-party modules that use `window` in Gatsby you need to add a `null` loader to its own webpack configuration to avoid the transpilation during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering). This is because `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser while `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server where obviously there isn't a [`window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@mapbox/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `test` value is a regular expression that will match a folder under `node_modules` so, ensure that the `/@mapbox/` is the right name.

Using a [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) may work but keep in mind that you are adding another package, another bundled files which may have a performance effect. The proposed snippet is a built-in solution that happens when you build your application.

Comment: Thanks, it works now ! I actually already tried that but I didn't relized that it's a regex and inserted the wrong value for the test!

So it's only about telling webpack - "Hey in the build process don't process those packages ?" they are then available without transpiration ?

Comment: Exactly what you said. Happy coding!